# Find values of a and b that will make the piece-wise function f(x) differentiable.

Tags: calculus

Find values of $a$ and $b$ that will make the piece-wise functions $f(x),g(x)$ differentiable.
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} (x-1)^2,& x ≤2 \\
            ax+b,& x>2\end{cases}
$$
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}ax+1,&   x<3\\
           b+\sqrt{x+1},&  x ≥3\end{cases}
$$

how am i suppose to start this question?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)$ is continuous at $x=2$ if:

- the function is continuous at $x=2$
- the two one-sided derivatives exist and are equal

Continuity requires

> \begin{align}\lim_{x\to2^-}{f(x)} &= \lim_{x\to2^+}{f(x)} \\[2ex] \lim_{x\to2^-}{(x-1)^2} &= \lim_{x\to2^+}{ax+b} \\[2ex] \implies 1 &= 2a+b \tag{1} \end{align}

Equating the two one-sided derivatives we get

> \begin{align} \lim_{x\to2^-}{2(x-1)} &= \lim_{x\to2^+}{a} \\[2ex] \implies 2 = a \tag{2} \end{align}

By (1) and (2): $\boxed{a=2,b=-3}$

See if you can find $a,b$ in a similar way to make $g(x)$ differentiable.